# overriding a function defined in jquery closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have a function defined in jquery closure and called by another function in the same closure. Could I override the function being called without changing the closure itself. See the code for example

```
(function($){
    function Myfunction(value)
    {
        //do something with the value
    }
    $('a').live('click',function(){
        MyFunction($(this).val())
    });
}(JQuery));
```

is there a way I can override `Myfunction` so that overriden copy of `Myfuntion` is called inside event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. [Functions defined inside closures are private](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) - and they:

> [cannot] be accessed directly from outside the anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

Writing `function f() {}` does several things with the function (although I wouldn't have guessed that keeping it out of the namespace was one of them).  Writing `var f = function() { }` treats f as an ordinary variable.